# zend framework images from database

Tags: database, image, zend-framework

Simply I'm looking to get images from a database displayed on page.

I have the image path saved as a blob in the database and then tried to echo the field in the source property of the img tag. But I get loads of random characters displayed and no image.. Below is what I have in the view of the page I want images displayed:

```
<div id="club_pictures">
    <img id="pic_1" src="<?php echo $this->clubs['pic_1']; ?>" />
    <img id="pic_2" src="<?php echo $this->clubs['pic_2']; ?>" />
    <img id="pic_3" src="<?php echo $this->clubs['pic_3']; ?>" />
</div>
```

If I then click view source in the browser I get the exact HTML I would want to display the image.

Thanks

Ric

Answer (score 0):

> I have the image path saved as a blob in the database

This is a contradiction. Your database field either contains the image path, or the binary data for the image. I'm assuming based on the rest of your question that it's the latter.

You can't just echo binary data to the page in this manner. You need to create a separate action or URL that loads the right image data based on the params in the URL, serves the appropriate headers (including the correct mime type) and then echos the binary data (without any other output). In your HTML example you would then echo the path to this action for each image. There should be plenty of examples explaining how to this with PHP if you have a hunt around.

Comment: So if iI wanted the image path I could just use varchar? and then echo the image path into the src field of the img tag?

Comment: Yes, you'd store the path to the image instead, and just echo that into the src of your img

Comment: I tried this, the field is varchar and has a limit of 1024 characters, I have checked and the image path is correct. I used -> <img src="<?php echo $this->clubs['pic_1'];?>" /> which is also correct and when I view source in firefox it looks like -> <img src="../images/clubs/5th_avenue_1.jpg" /> which is also correct. However no image.. Another strange thing is that when I add in just plain html to display the image I get nothing either..

Comment: Also if I click "<img src="images/clubs/5th_avenue_1.png" />" in the page source I get the following error:
http://pastebin.com/wk4gXsUA

Comment: I have just realized that 2 other images that are in my layout file dont appear when I first load the website they do however appear if I click my home link.. However if I navigate to the page that I am trying to get images from the database they disappear.. I have no idea what is going on here.. Have you ever heard of anything like this before?

Comment: Use absolute links instead of relatives ones, so: <img src="/images/clubs/5th_avenue_1.png" /> (note the slash at the start of the path)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try embedding images directly in HTML

```
$base64 = base64_encode($pictureBinary));
$image = '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $base64 . '"  />';
echo $image;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I should have used the baseUrl helper to give the absolute oath of the image file. As soon as I did this it worked! Thanks to [ZendFramework images not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182892/zendframework-images-not-loading) [This post][1]. My working code looks like this:

```
<img id="pic_1" src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl($this->clubs['pic_1']) ?>" />
```

Thanks Guys for the help!