# ZendFramework images not loading

Tags: zend-framework

I have a site I am developing in the ZendFramework and I have two social image pictures on the homepage. When I first load the page the images aren't there, however if I then click a link the images appear if I then click another link further into the site they disappear again, the images are in a div in the layout file they should be there all the time everything else in the layout file is apart from these.. I have been struggling on an issue of trying to echo image paths from a database in the src property of the  tag and couldn't get it to work then I realized this was happening and I am assuming it has something to do with the social images problem as the page where I want the database images to appear doesn't have the social links either..

Sorry for the rant I just don't really know how to explain the problem, hope it comes across ok, if you need any more information on this matter don't hesitate to ask!

Thanks in advance!

Rik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you echo the path to the image for the `src` attribute of the image tag, you should be using the [baseUrl helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl) so the path is always absolute and references your base URL.

For example, you would call `<?php echo $this->baseUrl('images/test.png') ?>` and that will result in something like `/zendapp/public/images` or `/images`.

I suspect what is happening is the image tag looks something like this: `<img src="images/thepic.png" />`.  You should make sure all images, CSS, Javascript references etc all use absolute paths like `/images` and avoid `../images`, `./images`, or `images` and the like.

Hope that helps.

Comment: great that's exactly what was wrong! You a life saver! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that was it!  Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

If don't wont use native view helper function `$this->baseUrl()`. Just add slash before image url `<img src="/images/thepic.png" alt="Some description" width="" heigth="" />`